# JSdoc use variable as default value

Tags: jsdoc3

I have a class that takes an `options` object with a lot of configurations inside.

```
const DEFAULTS = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: 3
  }
}

export default class Popper {
  constructor(options) {
    ...
```

I'm documenting the options properties manually but I'd like to define the default value using the one of the `DEFAULTS` variable.
Something like the following doesn't work, how can I do?

```
@param {Object} [options.b=DEFAULTS.b] - The defaults b options
```

Comment: Doesn't work how? It crashes? It does not look the way you want? (If the latter, then what does it look like, and what would you like it to look like instead?)

Comment: It just doesn't take the value from the `DEFAULTS.b` property, I would like it to take the value from it. Nothing more to add honestly

Answer (score 2):

I don't think jsdoc is prepared to substitute values, template-like. So an option here would be to document the constant, and make a reference to it, like so:

```js
/**
* Default values for options
* @param {number} [ a = 1 ] - this is a
* And so on...
*/
const DEFAULTS = {
  a: 1,
  b: {
    c: 2,
    d: 3
  }
}



export default class Popper {
  /**
  * Popper
  * @param {Object} [options = DEFAULT] See [[DEFAULT]]
  */
  constructor(options) {
    ...
```

That way the reader can properly be directed to these default values.